# Getting an Error \hbox badness

Tags: header-footer, paragraphs, box

\twocolumn[{
\maketitle
\begin{abstract}
Abstract text goes here.
\end{abstract}
\keywords{keyword1, keyword2, keyword3 etc.}
}]

sample.tex

LaTeX Warning: Label(s) may have changed. Rerun to get cross-references right.

sample.tex
58
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 58--58
 $[]$

sample.tex
58
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 58--58

sample.tex
174
Underfull \hbox (badness 3108) in paragraph at lines 174--177
\OT1/txr/m/it/9 The L[]T[]X Com-pan-ion\OT1/txr/m/n/9 . Addison-Wesley, Read-ing, Mas-

sample.tex
58
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 58--58
 $[]$

sample.tex
58
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 58--58

sample.tex
174
Underfull \hbox (badness 3108) in paragraph at lines 174--177
\OT1/txr/m/it/9 The L[]T[]X Com-pan-ion\OT1/txr/m/n/9 . Addison-Wesley, Read-ing, Mas-

Comment: `Underfull \hbox (badness 10000)` messages are usually due to ``\\`` to “leave blank lines”. You fix them by removing the wrong ``\\`` tokens. The other message seems to be due to a difficult paragraph in the bibliography, but the sample is misleading: you aren't going to cite the LaTeX companion, are you? By the way, you seem to have `\usepackage{txfonts}`. Don't: change it into `\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}`.

Answer (score 1):

I can't comment due to not enough reputation, but there's no way to help you unless you post the lines from `sample.tex` which are indicated in the error messages.

On a small note, what document class are you using? If it's `amsart`, the abstract should precede the title.